# Nested attributes form not rendering fields_for attributes properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's the code:

```
= form_for @form do |f|
  = f.fields_for :questions do |q|
    %p
      = q.object.content
      = q.fields_for :answers do |a|
        %p= a.text_area :content
```

What the name attribute on the `text_area` should be `form[questions_attributes][0][answer_attribute][content]` but it's showing. `form[questions_attributes][0][answers][content]`.

Here's my models.

```
# answer.rb
  belongs_to :question

# question.rb
  has_one :answer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer

# form.rb
  has_many :questions, :order => 'position ASC'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
```

So what I'm getting in the log is `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: answers`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

## update

here's the log so you can see what's being passed:

```
Started POST "/forms/16" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Mar 09 16:53:58 -0500 2012
  Processing by FormsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update Form", "utf8"=>"✓", "id"=>"16", "authenticity_token"=>"mcRJP8XgvE0Cl1JsPryER47+Hbx5DwpEveR1m0R7S6k=", "form"=>{"opportunity_id"=>"1", "questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"101", "answers"=>{"content"=>"asdfasdf"}}, "1"=>{"id"=>"102", "answers"=>{"content"=>"asdfasdf"}}, "2"=>{"id"=>"103", "answers"=>{"content"=>"asdfasdf"}}, "3"=>{"id"=>"104", "answers"=>{"content"=>""}}, "4"=>{"id"=>"105", "answers"=>{"content"=>""}}, "5"=>{"id"=>"106", "answers"=>{"content"=>""}}, "6"=>{"id"=>"107", "answers"=>{"content"=>""}}, "7"=>{"id"=>"108", "answers"=>{"content"=>""}}}, "status"=>"Not Reviewed", "current_step"=>"", "account_id"=>"1"}}
  SQL (0.8ms)   SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'

  Form Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "forms".* FROM "forms" WHERE "forms"."id" = 16 LIMIT 1
  Question Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" IN (101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108) AND ("questions".form_id = 16) ORDER BY position ASC
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: answers
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: answers
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: answers
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: answers
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: answers
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: answers
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: answers
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: answers
Redirected to http://vol.dev/forms/16
Completed 302 Found in 208ms
```

## Update 2

When I add `answers` to `attr_accessible` in `question.rb` I get `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: answers)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left everything in my models as is but I did this to the form:

```
 = f.fields_for :questions do |q|
    = q.fields_for :answer, q.object.answer do |a|
      = a.hidden_field :question_id, :value => q.object.id
      = a.hidden_field :form_id, :value => @form.id
      %p
        = a.label :content, q.object.content
        %br
        = a.text_area :content
```

And it works perfectly. If there's any refining or anything feel free to comment on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have attr_accessible for questions in form.rb

```
attr_accessible :questions_attributes
```

You might have to add all other fields in form.rb too to attr_accessible.

Comment: Already have that in my `form.rb`. So that's not it unfortunately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on my end Marc.

The two reasons why this was not working for you are:

1. Your association was a `has_one` between `question` and `answer` so you need to use the singular version in your `fields_for` argument:

   `q.fields_for :answer`
2. You need to build a answer for the question (in your controller, preferably):

   `question.build_answer`

You ended up doing these in your new form code that you posted as an answer but I thought I would explain *why* it worked.

Cheers,

JP